# FlutterFlow - Is there a way to display a widget on top of other apps?

Tags: flutter, widget, overlay, mobile-application, flutterflow

I am very beginner in flutterFlow and I would to create a mobile app.
For this app, I want to create a clickable widget that can display on the home screen or on top of other apps, so that you can launch my app whenever you want.
Once you have clicked the widget, i want to create a selective screenshot, so that you can select a zone of the screen that you want to capture. This screenshot will be reuse after.

Please anyone can tell me first if this is possible with FlutterFlow or do i have to code in Flutter the whole application ?

Thank you very much !

I saw in the doc that FlutterFlow proposes the module Stack but this is not what i am looking for.
But I didn't find any clue that let me think this is possible with FlutterFlow